# Clicking TabBarButton from the sideNavController REFrostedViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if it is possible to click ButtonA/TabBarButton that is on Controller2, from Controller1 programmatically.

My Controller1 acts as a sideNav, so what I'm actually doing is when I click a certain link, First, I close the sideNav, Second, try to click the second tab item. But it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my sample code in trying to click the tab.

EDIT : Here is my code>

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForCell:self.cellToClick]])
    {
        //closes sideNav
        [self hideMenuViewController];

        //Doesn't go to tab2
         FirstController *controller1 = [FirstController new];
        controller1.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [controller1.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    }
}
```

To make it clear, I have two buttons in my sideNav, that needs to act as the two tabBarButtons of my tabBarController.

Example, I clicked the first button of my sideNav, it will close the sideNav then click the first Tab of my tabBarController, and so on.

Any idea what's going on here?

EDIT : Tried doing this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if ([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForCell:self.cellToClick]])
        {
            //closes sideNav
            [self hideMenuViewController];

            //Doesn't go to tab2


           FirstController *controller1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstController"];
           controller1.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [controller1.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
            }
        }
```

**ANSWER**

```
if ([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForCell:self.homeCell]])
    {
    [self.frostedViewController hideSideNavController];

    TabBarViewController *hmtvc = [((UINavigationController*)self.frostedViewController.contentViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    hmtvc.selectedViewController = [hmtvc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

I already have an instance of my NavigationController **THAT** is embedded in my TabBarController. The real problem is that I thought at first the I don't have an instance yet. but I have. It is on the third party that I'm using named REFrostedViewController. It holds the instance of the NavigationController.

The frostedViewController.contentViewController holds the NavigationController embeded in the TabBarController, now I just need to access the TabBarController using the NavController.

I did it using :

```
[((UINavigationController*)self.frostedViewController.contentViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

then now I have access to the instance of my tabBarController I just selected the tab that I want, in my case the second tab so I used.

```
hmtvc.selectedViewController = [hmtvc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: add your tried code for this .

Comment: New Edit @KKRocks

Comment: Can you add photo , It will be nice to see clearly.

Comment: You have provided conflicting names to the controllers.So i will assume Controller 1 is the side nav and Contorller 2 is the tabbar controller. It seems what you are doing is that you are allocating a new tabbar controller and assigning selectedviewcontorller on it. You should be keeping a reference to the tabbar contorller which is already displayed in the side nav and then set selectedViewController on that.

Comment: I'm sorry @ArpitBParekh but uploading images is restricted from work. Have new more clear objective in my edit.

Comment: @Windindi can you create an answer for that. And I'll try to do it, and see results. Anyway, you're right. Controller 1 is the sideNav

Comment: The same thing I am saying as said by @Windindi.

Comment: So there are two things ? SideNavigation and TabBarController ?

Comment: Yes youre right

Comment: In your Side Navigation if you click on second tab, the view that open is a TabBarController.

Comment: The sidenav overlaps the tabbar controller, if you click the button in side nav the sidenav closes and must click the tabbar button of the tab bar controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127691/discussion-between-arpit-b-parekh-and-edward-beringuela).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think that your firstViewController is already created, so that only you can move tabs and every operation you can do.

Now on tableView did select row at indexpath, **you are again creating a new ViewController object,**  That is not good.

**What is already there  and you are created a new object.**

That is not appropriate.

If you understand this much I can explain you more.

You need to find the tabBarController's reference in your app lifecycle.

That is how tabBarControlelr is associated with self.frostedViewController and then you can select the index os=f a tabBarController.

Comment: Yes, I know the concept of that, and I know that I'm creating another instance of my Controller 2, w/c makes it not work, I want to know how can I access the existing one.

Comment: Please tell us how you are creating SideNav with XIB or programmatically.

Comment: It is also a View controller on the storyboard

Comment: Let me read the question again, and I may help you more. REFrostedViewController is a ThirdParty ?

Comment: Yes it is a 3rd party the allows you to overlap another view controller

Comment: Hi arpit, see chat pls.

Comment: Hi,@Edward, please post your solution in your question, by writing in bold letters as ANSWER and post your answer like coding and explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitBParekh. I wouldn't come up to this without your help!

Comment: Ya, It's ok man, thanks. Have a best luck, from bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0):

Try this create your controller instance as below if you use stroryboard

```
FirstController *controller1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboard id"];
```

or try this for set tab index

```
[yourtabbatInstance setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it still doesn't change tabs. see edits.

Comment: @KKRocks it will not work, because you are creating new instance,  the instance is already in the memory....